# Wordpress php Как в functions.php применить стиль к определенной странице а не для всех

Tags: php, wordpress

У меня есть код но он применяться ко всем страницам, а я хочу применить этот код только к странице 22.php . И аналогичный вопрос к скриптам

```
function add_style_theme(){
wp_enqueue_style('main_styles' , get_template_directory_uri(). '/assets/styles/main_styles.css');
wp_enqueue_style('responsive' , get_template_directory_uri(). '/assets/styles/responsive.css');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В даном случае стоит применить хук `is_page()` для станиц, или `is_single()`, `is_singular()` для постов и пост типов.
Пример для страницы с `post_name` = `моя-страница`:

```
function add_style_theme(){
if(is_page('моя-страница')){
    wp_enqueue_style('main_styles' , get_template_directory_uri(). '/assets/styles/main_styles.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('responsive' , get_template_directory_uri(). '/assets/styles/responsive.css');
    }
}
```

Или для всех постов пост типов `тип1`, `тип2`:

```
function add_style_theme(){
if(is_singular(array('тип1','тип2'))){
    wp_enqueue_style('main_styles' , get_template_directory_uri(). '/assets/styles/main_styles.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('responsive' , get_template_directory_uri(). '/assets/styles/responsive.css');
    }
}
```

Если же конкретно надо подключить стиль, если используется часть темплейта 22.php, то проще всего в functions.php добавить наш екшин:

```
function add_style_theme(){
    wp_enqueue_style('main_styles' , get_template_directory_uri(). '/assets/styles/main_styles.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('responsive' , get_template_directory_uri(). '/assets/styles/responsive.css');
}
add_action('my_custom_styles_for_page', 'add_style_theme');
```

И в коде непосредстенно 22.php вызвать подключение, написав в начале например:

```
do_action('my_custom_styles_for_page');
```